# How to manage subtype tag for asset in Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode7, xcasset

Xcode 7 allow Image Set Type to use subtype tag — Asset Catalog Format Reference.

Subtype tag have the following values:
- Tag not included, the image is for a 3.5-inch iPhone screen.
- retina4, the image is for a 4-inch iPhone screen.
- 736h, the image is for a 4.7-inch iPhone screen.
- 667h, the image is for a 5.5-inch iPhone screen.

But Xcode does show have any option to manage this tag. So how to manage it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filled a bug report to Apple and this is the answer;

> This issue behaves as intended based on the following:
>
> There is currently no publicly supported values subtype in the CAR
>   file. Previously, this was used for R4, but that was retired when we
>   stopped supporting the old 3.5” displays. Additional subtypes for the
>   new 6 and 6s display were never defined.
>
> We are now closing this bug report.